# Sitecore 9 - Authors accessing profile information for content items

Tags: content-editor, content-management

Is there any out-of-the-box way in Sitecore 9 for content authors to access the sitecore user profile information and put it INTO the content fields.

For example, in the experience editor - could a author add something to a string field like `Welcome {Profile.FullName}!` .  I have seen some third party libraries for 8.x that seem to offer the ability to create your own tokens -- is this still the only applicable way?  Will these work with the content items?

Comment: Hey Watson, can you explain a bit more your scenario. When an Author create a new page you want to have in the title something like  Welcome {Author Name} ?

Comment: Yes so - rather than create a hard-coded razor view adding in the current user's profile information - is there any way for the Content Authors to dynamically add that to what they are creating in the experience editor.  So we might have a piece of content, containing a string field, which looks like "Welcome {token}" where token is replaced with the current logged in user's fullname (from their Sitecore User Profile).

Answer (score 2):

In Sitecore 9 you need to customize a bit to replace customtokens with User Name.

In next example you will replace $user with the name of the user

First off all you need to extend MasterVariablesReplacer:

```
public class CustomMasterVariablesReplacer: MasterVariablesReplacer
    {
        protected override string ReplaceValues(string text, Func<string> defaultName, Func<string> defaultId, Func<string> defaultParentName, Func<string> defaultParentId)
        {
            if (text.Length == 0 || text.IndexOf('$') < 0)
                return text;
            ReplacerContext context = this.GetContext();
            if (context != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in (SafeDictionary<string, string>)context.Values)
                    text = text.Replace(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
            }
            text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$name", defaultName, context);
            text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$id", defaultId, context);
            text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$parentid", defaultParentId, context);
            text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$parentname", defaultParentName, context);
            text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$date", (Func<string>)(() => DateUtil.IsoNowDate), context);
            text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$time", (Func<string>)(() => DateUtil.IsoNowTime), context);
            text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$now", (Func<string>)(() => DateUtil.IsoNow), context);
            text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$user", (Func<string>)(() => Sitecore.Context.User.Name), context);
            return text;
        }
    }
```

You need to register new master variable replacer in a config file :

```
<configuration xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
    <settings>
    <setting name="MasterVariablesReplacer" value="YourNamespace.CustomMasterVariablesReplacer,YourDll"/>
    </settings>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is awesome -- thanks!!  I will try it out then mark this as the answer.

Comment: Vlad -- will this work for the content delivery nodes as well?  So the content author will create a field with Hi ${username}  - in the content delivery node, when a user logs in - I want them to see their user name on the page.

Comment: it will work for content delivery. Can you write on sitecore slack your scenario, I guess you missunderstand how CM write content to CD using publishing...